# Hide a sibling of parent element using css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have something this type of html

```
<div class='box'>
   <input type="checkbox" id="c1">
   <label for="c1">Check me to hide</label>
</div>
<div id='con-1'>Div to hide when checked</div>
```

And I want to hide my div with id `con-1` when checkbox with id `c1` is checked.
I am not able to find a selector for this.

PS: I can't change my html structure and also can't use javascript or jQuery.

You can try live code here: http://jsbin.com/xapaweqoju/edit?html,css,output

Comment: It is not possible by pure css. You have to use javascript or jquery.

Comment: Impossible by just pure CSS.

Comment: Ok, I will check then, what I can change.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this by using css You Must change your html structure if you want to do this using css because CSS has no Parent selector yet

Answer (score -1):

The only way is to use js or change your html like this:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #con-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='box'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1">
  <label for="1">Check me to hide</label>
  <div id='con-1'>Div to hide when checked</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `PS: I can't change my html structure and also can't use javascript or jQuery.` There are enough other solution with JS for example... But none which fits the requirements...